# Avoiding repetitive conditions in the select case and where clause

Tags: sql, select, case, where-clause, repeat

I have a table say TAB1 with the following columns -
**USER_ID NUMBER(5),**
**PHN_NO1 CHAR(20),**
**PHN_NO2 CHAR(20)**
I have to fetch records from TAB1 into another table TAB2 such that all records with either one of the two or both PHN_NO1 and PHN_NO2 are of length 10 and begin with 5.
 
If in a record,say only PHN_NO1 satisfies the condition and PHN_NO2 does not then, TAB2.P1 should be same as TAB1.PHN_NO1 but TAB2.P2 should be NULL.
If neither of the two satisfy the condition, then the record should not be inserted into TAB2

Structure of TAB2 would be as 
**USER_ID number(5)**- holding the ROWID of the record selected from TAB1
**P1 char(10)**- holding TAB1.PHN_NO1 if it is of length 10 and begins with 5, otherwise NULL
**P2 char(10)**- holding TAB1.PHN_NO2 if it is of length 10 and beigns with 5, otherwise NULL

I could write the below query to achieve the above, but the conditions in the CASE and WHERE are repetitive. Please suggest a way to achieve the above in a better way.

---

> CREATE TABLE TAB2
>   AS
>   SELECT
>   USER_ID,
>   CASE WHEN 
>   (LENGTH(TRIM(PHN_NO1)) = 10 AND  TRIM(PHN_NO1) like '5%')
>   THEN
>   CAST(TRIM(PHN_NO1) as CHAR(10))
>   ELSE
>   CAST(NULL as CHAR(10))
>   END AS P1,
>   CASE (LENGTH(TRIM(PHN_NO2)) = 10 AND  TRIM(PHN_NO2) like '5%')
>   THEN
>   CAST(TRIM(PHN_NO2) as CHAR(10))
>   ELSE
>   CAST(NULL as CHAR(10))
>   END AS P2
>   WHERE
>   (LENGTH(TRIM(PHN_NO1) = 10 AND TRIM(PHN_NO1) like '5%')
>   OR
>   (LENGTH(TRIM(PHN_NO2) = 10 AND TRIM(PHN_NO2) like '5%')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can!  You do have to use *some* conditions though:

```
INSERT INTO New_Phone 
        SELECT user_id, phn_no1, phn_no2
        FROM (SELECT user_id,
              CASE WHEN LENGTH(TRIM(phn_no1)) = 10 AND TRIM(phn_no1) like '5%'
                   THEN SUBSTR(phn_no1, 1, 10) ELSE NULL END phn_no1, 
              CASE WHEN LENGTH(TRIM(phn_no2)) = 10 AND TRIM(phn_no2) like '5%'
                   THEN SUBSTR(phn_no2, 1, 10) ELSE NULL END phn_no2
              FROM Old_Phone) Old
        WHERE phn_no1 IS NOT NULL
        OR phn_no2 IS NOT NULL;
```

(I have a working SQL Fiddle [example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/9a7eb/2).)

This should work on any RDBMS.  Note that, because of your data, this isn't likely to be *less* performant than your original (which would not have used an index, given the `TRIM()`).  It's also not likely to be *better*, given that most major RDBMSs are able to re-use the results of deterministic functions per-row.

Oh, it should be noted that, internationally, phone numbers can be up to 15 digits in length (with a minimum in-country of 6 or less).  Maybe use `VARCHAR` (and save yourself some `TRIM()`s, too)?  And `INTEGER` (or `BIGINT`, maybe `TINYINT`) is more often used for surrogate ids, `NUMBER` is a little strange.

Comment: Thanks! This solves the purpose. This was just a simplified explanation of what I waned to achieve, so phone number lengths actually do not matter in my case. Thanks a lot for answering :)